# How can i locate files in spring that arent in the same level as the spring.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Let's suppose i have a message source bean like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property>
    <list>
        <value>mymessages</value>
        <value>mymessages_en_US</value>
    </list>
</property>

</bean>
```

This will only work if my .properties are in the same level as the spring.xml
how would i locate the files if my .properties where in a folder properties
inside the project?

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundleMessasgeSource loads resource bundles from the classpath.

If you ensure that the folder where the properties files reside is on the classpath then Spring should load them.

Comment: what about the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer post processor will it find the file anywhere in the classpath too? those are the only two beans with resources i've learned so far.

Comment: See the Spring Documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) for an example of how to find property resources on the classpath. If you have problems you should either search for an answer or ask a new question.